Continuous injection to manifold with boundary
Let $M^n$ be an n dimensional manifold with boundary. Assume $U$ is open in $M^n$. Let $f:U\rightarrow M^n$ be a continuous injection open map. Then show that $f(U\cap \partial{M})=\partial{M}$
I am stuck on this. I think invariance of domain should be used, but I dont see how. Also I think it might be a typo and we maybe might have $f(U\cap \partial{M})\subseteq \partial{M}$ instead.

Yes, it is a typo.

From the fact that $U \subset M$ is open and that $f : U \to M$ is continuous, injective, and open, it follows that $V=f(U)$ is open in $M$ and that $f$ restricts to a homeomorphism $f : U \to V$. Furthermore, both of $U$ and $V$ are $n$-dimensional manifolds with boundary, and we have $\partial U = U \cap \partial M$ and $\partial V = V \cap \partial M$. It therefore suffices to prove that $f(\partial U)=\partial V$.
I would suggest that instead of trying to directly apply the invariance of domain theorem, you instead apply one of the homology tools that is closely associated to the proof of invariance of domain. This tool is a simple relative homology formula which distinguishes between interior points and boundary points for any $n$-dimensional manifold $N^n$ with boundary; namely, for any $x \in N$,

$x \in \partial N \iff H_n(N,N-x) \approx 0$
$x \in \text{int}(N) \iff H_n(N,N-x) \approx \mathbb Z$

Applying this for $N=U$ as well as $N=V$, and using that $f$ induces a homeomorphism $f : (U,U-x) \mapsto (V,V-f(x))$ in the category of pairs which in turn induces an isomorphism $f_* : H_n(U,U-x) \to H_n(V,V-f(x))$ of relative homology groups, we get a chain of equivalences
$$x \in \partial U \iff H_n(U,U-x) \approx 0 \iff H_n(V,V-f(x)) \approx 0 \iff f(x) \in \partial V
$$
and similarly for the interiors.

Thank you! This is very informative
